# taking value of service into view of Component IN Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services

I want to display the service into the view of component 
for now I have fetched the data of service from and print it in the console ,
But I want to store the same data int he variable or Array  and I want to dispaly it into the view of the component

I am putting the details of the code below

**Countrycode.service.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class CodeCountryService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://country.io/names.json').pipe(map(
     (response) => response.json()
    )).subscribe(

      (data) => console.log(data)
         );

  }
}
```

I made a module  **countryCode.ts**

```
export interface IcounrtyCode {

    code: string;
    country: string;
}
```

**code-counrty.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CodeCountryService } from '../services/Contrycode.service';
import {IcounrtyCode} from '../module/countryCode';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-code-country',
  templateUrl: './code-country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./code-country.component.css']
})
export class CodeCountryComponent implements OnInit {

  counrtyCode: IcounrtyCode[];

  constructor(private _CodeCountryService: CodeCountryService) { }

  getData() {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.counrtyCode =  this._CodeCountryService.getData();

  }

}
```

I want to fetch the data and display it to the view of the component

But I am getting error in file  **code-country.component.ts**  while initializing counrtyCode in  ngOnInit() function

> error is ->
>
> [ts] Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'IcounrtyCode[]'.
>   Property 'length' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Comment: You should really check your spelling in the code. I see `contry` and `counrty` in several places (variable or other names). This is really bad readability of your code.

Comment: can you check my model which is made for the service Service is -: {"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso"} Module is -: export interface IcounrtyCode { code: string; country: string; } can you check If my module is correct

Answer (score 0):

subscribe it from the component instead of service. Return the observable from the service.

```
 getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://country.io/names.json').pipe(map(
     (response) => response.json()
    ))

  }
```

Now subscribe it inside the component.

```
 this._CodeCountryService.getData().subscribe( 
      (data) => {
       this.counrtyCode = data
  });
```

Comment: thanks , but when I tryied to print country name only using  console.log(this.counrtyCode.country);

full code : - 

ngOnInit() {
    this._CodeCountryService.getData().subscribe(
     (data) => {
       this.counrtyCode =  data;
      console.log(this.counrtyCode.country);
     }


I am getting error like : [ts] Property 'country' does not exist on type 'IcounrtyCode[]'.

Comment: I used   counrtyCode: IcounrtyCode[];  and then  I used .subscribe( (data) => { this.counrtyCode = data; )

Comment: `subscribe( (data: IcounrtyCode[]) => { this.counrtyCode = data; ) –`

Comment: I implimented but Still I am getting error 
erroe : - 

error TS2339: Property 'country' does not exist on type 'IcounrtyCode[]'.

Comment: `this.counrtyCode` is an array, not an object. u cant access like that. use `this.counrtyCode[0].country`

Comment: can you check my model which is made for the service 

Service is -: 

{"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso"}

Module is -:

export interface IcounrtyCode {

    code: string;
    country: string;
} 

can you check If my module is correct

Answer (score 0):

in your service.

```
 getData() {
   return this.http.get('http://country.io/names.json') 
   .map((response: Response) => response.json())
 }
```

then subscribe in your component

```
 this._CodeCountryService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
 this.counrtyCode = data
}, 
 (error)=>{

});
```

Comment: thanks but when I am trying to access the name of the country using 
console.log(this.counrtyCode.country);  I am getting error : -   [ts] Property 'country' does not exist on type 'IcounrtyCode[]'.

Comment: If you console.log(data), do you see the data or does this give you a null or undefined?

Comment: can you check my model which is made for the service 

Service is -: 

{"BD": "Bangladesh", "BE": "Belgium", "BF": "Burkina Faso"}

Module is -:

export interface IcounrtyCode {

    code: string;
    country: string;
} 

can you check If my module is correct

Comment: Yes when i write console.log(data), I see the data .